# Files open as completely empty in Dreamweaver

Tags: file, dreamweaver

While using dreamweaver I connected to my website and attempted to work on a file on my remote server (the actual site server) and when I opened it there was NO CODE AT ALL. When I logged into the actual site, the file functioned normally and when I went to the file manager on the actual site, the file was perfectly fine.  Please help!
Also ,when I try to open a file, it gives me an error "This page may have dynamically-related files that can only be discovered by the server" When I tell Dreamweaver to try and discover them it tells me they "could not be resolved". I have never had this dynamic file thing pop up and I do not have any dynamically-related files that I am aware of, I do not even know what they are and I opened these same files without an issue last week when I updated some.

Comment: Have you tried turning off and on again?

Comment: Yes, and even rebooted my system

Comment: ♚ Keep calm and carry on. Maybe you should abandon Dreamweaver. Personally, I simply use a combination of Notepad++ and WinSCP (Windows); Fraise and Cyberduck (or something else that's free, on Mac); or Geany and 'default file explorer/navigator' (Ubuntu family).

Comment: I am a hacker and have come to depend on much of the functionality and ease of creation that Dreamweaver supports. Worked fine last week, and oddly, some files show up fine, but only a handful and there is no rhyme or reason that I can determine.

Comment: Not a "hacker" but someone who has no formal training in computer programming. Just a  clarification! :)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Found the answer, was a corrupted cache. Followed directions here:

Dreamweaver's cache is kept in a file in its Configuration folder. That file name depends on OS:

```
For Windows  it is WinFileCache-<randomString>.dat
For  MAC  it is MacFileCache-<randomString>.dat

  Deleting of that file clears the cache. After restarting Dreamweaver is creating new one. Location of the cache file differs for each version and operating system. Here is a list of locations depending on DW version and OS:

For Dreamweaver CC:

    Vista, 7 & 8: C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Adobe\Dreamweaver CC\<language>\Configuration
    XP: C:\Documents and Settings\<username>\Application Data\Adobe\Dreamweaver CC\<language>Configuration\
```

Once I cleared it and rebooted and restarted it worked fine!

Comment: this does not recover emptied file